# Telerik Grid: Issue with Select

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, telerik

I have the following databinding. The actual URL  assigned  to  my Edit button and  Select button is : `/Home/Selection/`. I do not think that this should be the case.
Why does the action for my select button get assigned to my edit button also. They both have `/Home/Selection` for the `Controller/Action`

My Delete button has the correct action called delete. `/Home/Delete/` based on the binding definition below.

See databind below, The databinding binds an *action* called *"Selection"* and `controller` called `Home`. I would think that it would call `~/Home/Selection/5?` I get a **404 not found** error when clicking the select button. Any help is appreciated.

1. Why am I getting 404 error.
2. why does the edit and select button have the same action assigned?

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {            
            ProjectViewModel objProjectViewModel = new ProjectViewModel();
            objProjectViewModel.ProjectList = Repository.GetProjects();


            return View(objProjectViewModel);

        }



[HttpPost]
[GridAction]
  public ActionResult Selection(long id)
        {
            ProjectViewModel objProjectViewModel = new ProjectViewModel();
            objProjectViewModel.ProjectHierarchy = Repository.GetProjects(id);

            ViewBag["id"] = id;
            return View(objProjectViewModel);
        }
```

DATABINDING

```
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Server().Select("Selection", "Home")
                                            .Insert("Insert", "Home")
                                            .Update("Update", "Home")
                                            .Delete("Delete", "Home")
                                            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what telerik support said:

This is by design. The grid uses a query string argument to determine that it is in edit mode. You can see this in our online demo.
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/Grid/EditingServerSide/1?mode=InLine&type=Text&Grid-mode=edit

the Telerik team

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a DataKey set on the Grid?

```
Html.Telerik().Grid(...)
.DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add(o => o.Id))
```